# difference between HDMI to VGA Converter and "Active HDMI to VGA Converter"

Tags: hdmi

Is there any difference between HDMI to VGA Converter and "Active HDMI to VGA Converter".

There are two product available in amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Usually "active" means the converter has special circuitry (chips) inside, for converting one kind of signal to another. "Passive" adapters are more-or-less direct connections between differently shaped plugs/sockets.

However, HDMI and VGA use fundamentally different signals, so *all* HDMI-to-VGA converters are "active", whether they mention it on the product title or not.

(Although "passive" HDMI/VGA cables *do* show up in stores, these are garbage.)

On the other hand, HDMI-to-DVI *can* use simple passive adapters, because DVI-D and HDMI both use the same basic kind of video signal.